# Using revalidate in NEXT.JS

Tags: next.js

At the moment, I am trying to make an application with NEXT.JS. When I come to `revalidate` of page using method ISR. I very confused to understand how it works for the system or how is it auto to rebuild data of the pages in the system?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think ISR as the combination of the SSR and SSG.

1. When you defined `revalidate` in `getStaticProps`, Next.js will generate the static HTML during build time because `getStaticProps` is exported.
2. When a user makes a request to the page, that Next.js app will serve the statically generally page. In fact, all the users will see the same page.
3. After the validation time is reached, the first user request to the page will make Next.js server-side rendered the page again. The generated page will be saved locally.
4. All users will be served with that newly generated HTML until the next validation. We then go back to step 3 again.